# (next.js typescript tailwind) content doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, tailwind-css

I made a next project with `Typescript` and `Tailwind CSS`

`src/app/page.tsx:`

```
import Button from "@/component/button";
import Image from "next/image";
import shadup from '../../public/a.jpg'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 gap-4 bg-gradient-to-b from-red-600 to-yellow-800">
    <div className="border-4 border-blue-700 text-3xl text-amber-500">Wandering Swordsman</div>
    <div>  
      <Image 
      src={shadup}
      width={300}
      height={250}
      alt={''}
      className="border-4 rounded-full border-grey-600">
      </Image>
      </div>
    <div className="font-bold  py-2 px-4 border-4 border-blue-700  bg-blue-50 rounded-full text-red-700">
      <Button href='https://muhammad-six.vercel.app/'>Main site</Button>
    </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

`src/app/dashboard/page.tsx:`

```
import React from 'react'

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>welcome to Dashboard route</div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard;
src/component/button.tsx:
import Link from 'next/link';

interface ButtonProps { 
  href: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function Button({ href, children }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Link href={href} passHref>
      <div className="">
        {children}
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

`src/app/layout.tsx:`

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import link from "next/link";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
      <header>
      <link href="/">Home</link>
      <link href="/dashboard">Dashboard</link>
      </header>     
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

now the problem is no content other than buttons is shown: if clicked home(or the page that is shown at the starting), then content that should be shown at home doesn't show and only buttons are seen and if clicked dashboard then only shows the buttons and no content that should be on dashboard appears either

I have tried getting it but it gives nonsensical answers like wrap link titles in anchor tag which gives an error, I tell it the error, and it says remove anchor tag or says import Link instead of link

Comment: In case of next time, it would be great to add the version of Next.js you're working with because of the changes introduced with the release of Next.js 13.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to render `{children}` in src/app/layout.tsx:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <header>
    <link href="/">Home</link>
    <link href="/dashboard">Dashboard</link>
    </header>
    {children}
  </body>
</html>
```